# Script de backup do cPanel movendo arquivos para pasta errada

Tags: bash, backup, cpanel

Euj tenho este script para backup full do cPanel que funciona bem:  (https://github.com/pietromalerba/cPanel-Full-Backup-Script).

Eu segui exatamente as configurações da orientação, criei duas pastas `/backups/backup_daily` e `/backups/backup_monthly` e os cron jobs correspondentes.

O problema é que o backup mensal está sendo sempre movido para a pasta do backup diário.

E mesmo que eu mova manualmente o arquivo de backup mensal para a pasta correta dele, quando o script roda novamente o arquivo volta ser movido para a pasta diária, misturando-se assim com os demais arquivos, incorretamente.

Eu achoque o problema está na linha 47 do **backup.sh**:

`find $HOME -type f -name "backup-*" -exec mv {} $BACKUP_FOLDER/ \;`

Alguém saberia me dizer como consertar isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido mudando a linha 47 para:

```
find $HOME/* -maxdepth 0 -type f -name "backup-*" -exec mv {} $BACKUP_FOLDER/ \;
```